# control bandwidth in wcf file upload

Tags: wcf, file, upload, bandwidth

I have a wcf application to upload files from clients to my server. I am using NetTcpbinding and WSHttpBinding but I need to control the bandwidth, how can I accomplish this??

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no built-in throughput throttling at the WCF level. You might be able to leverage the QoS features built into Windows for that, but honestly, I've never tried it. I guess you could always write your own transport channel that supports it, though.